# Show clickable item only on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an editable div that opens a toolbar below it when it's focused. How can I click on the created item (`#toolbar`) before it disappears again on blur? Is there a cleaner way than setting a long setTimeout?

```js
$('#child').on('focus', function(e) {
  $('#parent').append('<div id="toolbar">Click me and an alert should open!</div>');
});
$('#child').on('blur', function(e) {
  var $item = $('#parent').find('#toolbar');
  $item.css('opacity', 0)
  setTimeout(function() {
    $item.remove();
  }, 100);
});
$(document).on('click', '#toolbar', function(e) {
  alert('How can I get this to show without a mega-long setTimeout?');
});
```

```css
#toolbar { cursor: pointer; }
#child { white-space: pre-wrap; }
#child { line-height: 1em; height: 1em; overflow: hidden; }
#child:focus { height: 3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" contenteditable="true">Long text
coming here
and here</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, I'd just add a `transition` effect to the `opacity`.

Edit: Upon testing, it is found that clicking (which requires a mouse down followed by a mouse up for it to be a click) on the `div` may sometimes missed by the browser due to the `div` disappearing too soon (the 100 milliseconds removal). You may either change to using `mousedown` to create a more consistent behavior, or extend the item removal timer.

Edit: Based on your updated requirement, `mousedown` seems to work well.

```js
$('#child').on('focus', function(e) {
  $('#parent').append('<div id="toolbar">Click me and an alert should open!</div>');
});
$('#child').on('blur', function(e) {
  var $item = $('#parent').find('#toolbar');
  $item.css('opacity', 0)
  setTimeout(function() {
    $item.remove();
  }, 500);
});
$(document).on('mousedown', '#toolbar', function(e) {
  alert('How can I get this to show without a mega-long setTimeout?');
});
```

```css
#toolbar { cursor: pointer; }
#child { white-space: pre-wrap; }
#child { line-height: 1em; height: 1em; overflow: hidden; }
#child:focus { height: 3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" contenteditable="true">Long text
coming here
and here</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I made it a little more complicated and introduced an expandable feature to the text. Now the click is totally missed since it's moving location. Any workaround on that? See original post. Is there a way to make the click happen before the blur?

Comment: Use `mousedown`?

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. It even works without the timeout and opacity now! :)